# Why is my php page showing an error on the <?php tags

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to create a webpage which only uses PHP (there does not need to be any HTML elements) but when I run the page I get the following error:
[image]

Here is the code for my page:

```
<script>
<?php
    if(isset($_COOKIE['string']) and isset($_COOKIE['studentarrays'])){
        $string = $_COOKIE['string'];
        $array = explode(",",$string);
        array_shift($array);
        $studentstring = $_COOKIE['studentarrays'];
        $studentarrays = explode(",",$studentstring);

?>
    var array = <?php echo $studentarrays ?>;
    alert(array);
<?php
    }
?>
</script>
```

[image]

What have I done wrong?

Edit: As someone pointed out I had a SESSION variable without starting the session, so this part of the error has now been fixed. Also I had forgotten to include the session code when I copied my code to this website, sorry for the confusion.
Thank you for all the replies, it seems that I have made a fair few mistakes with this page so I have decided to go back and simplify this page as much as possible, removing anything which I did not need.
Here is my new code:

```
<script>
<?php
    include"databaseconnection.php";
    session_start();

    if(isset($_COOKIE['studentarrays'])){
        $studentstring = $_COOKIE['studentarrays'];
        $studentarrays = explode(",",$studentstring);
        $teacherid = $_SESSION['username'];
    }
?>
</script>
```

This seems to be working without errors now but I do not know exactly what it was causing the error. I will update this post if I figure out what part if the original code was causing the error, until then please ignore this question

Comment: Are you sure you started the session? On top of the page?

Comment: The error references '$_SESSION', which isn't in the code you have here.

Comment: @ŞahinErsever Oops thanks for the reminder, I had forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to passing arrays(php) to JS using JavaScript Object Notation(JSON).

Using `json_encode()` function: The function can take both single dimensional and multidimensional arrays.

```
const array = JSON.Parse("<?php echo json_encode($studentarrays) ?>");
    alert(array);
```

OR

```
const array = "<?php echo json_encode($studentarrays) ?>";
    console.log(array);
```

And also you can use PHP `implode()` function:
`implode()` function is used to build a string that becomes an array literal in JavaScript.

```
<?php
  
// Creating a PHP Array
$studentarrays = array('John', 'Foo', 'Bar');
  
?>
const array = "<?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $studentarrays) . '"]' ?>";
    console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, although the alert was just for testing purposes, and I have decided to remove it, but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `echo` on array.

If you want to assign PHP array to json array directly, it's not possible I guess. You could try using JSON, like this:

```php
<script>
<?php
    if(isset($_COOKIE['string']) and isset($_COOKIE['studentarrays'])){
        $string = $_COOKIE['string'];
        $array = explode(",",$string);
        array_shift($array);
        $studentstring = $_COOKIE['studentarrays'];
        $studentarrays = explode(",",$studentstring);

?>
    var array = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($studentarrays) ?>");
    alert(array);
<?php
    }
?>
</script>
```

Also, the error tells you that your `$_SESSION` is not defined, have you started session in this file/request cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Try check array contents using `empty()` instead of `isset()`